# the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found with angularjs and spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to upload multiple input type file with multiple="true" using angular js and spring mvc but i got exception from server is "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

here i will put my code below

my jsp is

```
 <html ng-app="myApp">
 <body>
       <div ng-controller="controller">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add"  ng-click="add();" />
          <form name="form" id="form"   ng-submit="submitRecord(blog)" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                   <div id="outerdiv" name="outerdiv">
                   </div>
          </form>
       </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

here i was generate input elements from angular controller after clicking add and input controls are generate in "".

my angular controller is

```
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('TechnoBlogs', ['ngRoute','ui.router']);
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
App.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {    

    /*$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8';*/
}],['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/create', {
       templateUrl: '/',
       controller: 'controller'
});

 }]);
var currentg1=0;

var controller = function($scope,$http,fileService){

$scope.blog = [];
/*var currentg1=0;*/
$scope.blog.desc=[];
$scope.blog.desccode=[];
$scope.blog.descimg=[];

$scope.add=function(){



var $div = angular.element("<br><div><label id='desc["+currentg1+"]'   for='desc["+currentg1+"]'>Description"+currentg1+"<span style='color: red;''>*</span></label><textarea rows='3' cols='6' id='desc["+currentg1+"]' name='desc["+currentg1+"]' ng-model='blog.desc["+currentg1+"]' required='required'></textarea> </div><br><div><label id='desccodeL["+currentg1+"]' for='desccodeL["+currentg1+"]''>Code "+currentg1+"</label><textarea rows='3' cols='6' id='desccode["+currentg1+"]' name='desccode["+currentg1+"]' ng-model='blog.desccode["+currentg1+"]''></textarea></div><div><label id='descimgL["+currentg1+"]' for='descimgL["+currentg1+"]'>Image "+currentg1+"</label><input type='file' id='descimg["+currentg1+"]' class='file' name='descimg["+currentg1+"]' my-file-upload='descimg["+currentg1+"]'  multiple/></div>");
var e=document.getElementById("outerdiv");


angular.element(e).append($div).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
      var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
      $compile($div)(scope);        
    });

    currentg1++;
};

$scope.submitRecord=function(blog){


var fd = new FormData();
var files=[];
for(var i=0;i<currentg1;i++)
{

    files[i] = fileService.getFile("descimg["+i+"]");
    console.log("files["+i+"] ---> "+files[i]);
}


fd.append("files",files);

alert(fd);
console.log("--->>> "+files);


$http.post("saveblog",fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).success(function(){
    alert("success");

})

};

};


App.service('fileService', function () {
 var file = {};
 var fileService = {};

 fileService.getFile = function (name) {
     return file[name];
};

 fileService.setFile = function (newFile, index, name) {
    if (index === 0 && file[name] === undefined)
    file[name] = [];
   file[name][index] = newFile;

 };

 return fileService;
})

 App.directive('myFileUpload', function (fileService) {
 return function (scope, element, attrs) {
     element.bind('change', function () {
      var index;

       var index_file = 0;
       for (index = 0; index < element[0].files.length; index++) {
       fileService.setFile(element[0].files[index], index_file, attrs.myFileUpload);
        index_file++;
    }
    index_file = 0;

  });
  }
 });
```

My spring controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveblog", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'")
public void saveblog(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{

    System.out.println("in multipart ");
    Iterator<String> itr=request.getFileNames();

    MultipartFile file=request.getFile(itr.next());

    String fileName=file.getOriginalFilename();
    System.out.println(fileName);

}
```

i also create a bean for multipart

```
  <bean id="multipartResolver"                class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="2097152" />
</bean>
```

after that still got exception

my response header is

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 949
```

my request header is

```
POST /technoblogs/blog/saveblog HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 209
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7uIEu9ax8IY8nCde
Referer: http://localhost:8080/technoblogs/blog/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=61816E4AB7F6905F688755CF22BC16FF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016324/2855530) will help you. What you are missing is a content header.

From the linked answer:

> Angular will POST as JSON even if you set the Content-Type to the correct value multipart/form-data. So we must transform our request manually to the correct data. … [using] a transformRequest function that does nothing as returning your original FormData … like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'newDocument',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    data: formData,
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
        return data; // do nothing! FormData is very good!
    }
})
```

Edit: Can you show us your HTTP response and/or request?

Comment: i was display my http request and response header in quetion.

don't know why response header is return error code 404 but when i print something in spring controller which have request mapping of "saveblog" its printed on console.