# react / expressjs / multer don't save image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

i send a file from "react dropzone component" to "node server" and try to upload this with "multer" but no show any error, the file no upload and req.file/s is undefined

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var msg = require('../helpers/MessageHandler');
var CM = require('../helpers/ContentMessages.json');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {       
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).any();

var path = '/enterprise';

router.post(path, function(req, res, next) {

    var enterprise = req.body.obj;

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.file);
    
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        
        if(err) {
             return res.status(500).json(msg.prototype.errorMsg(err));
        } else {
            return     res.status(200).json(msg.prototype.success(CM.message.success.doc_create, null));
        }
    });

});
```

the react component is somthing like [this](https://github.com/BBB/dropzone-redux-form-example/blob/master/src/App.js),
in the fetch function i send a object with all the fields

```js
insertObj (values) {

        console.info(values);
  
        const obj = JSON.stringify({obj: values});
        let url = '/api/v1/enterprise';
        const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Request-Method': '*'};

        const req = new Request(url, {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: obj});
  
        fetch(req)
            .then((response) => {

                return response.json();

            })
        .then((enterprise) => {
          console.log(enterprise);
        }).catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside multer req.files will be visible. So change your code to this:

```
upload(req, res, function(err) {
 var enterprise = req.body.obj;
    console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.files);
console.log(req.file); 
    if(err) {
         return res.status(500).json(msg.prototype.errorMsg(err));
    } else {
        return     res.status(200).json(msg.prototype.success(CM.message.success.doc_create, null));
    }
});
```

Also instead of 'Content-Type': 'application/json' there should be enctype='multipart/form-data'.

Comment: A little mistake but is undefined again

Comment: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: I hope you have already googled it but have you tried what is written here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089824/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-with-angularjs